# I2C Level Translator Question

Tags: mosfet, i2c, level-translation

In the I2C Voltage translation circuit below, does it matter which side (SDA1/SCL1 or SDA2/SCL2) is the master and which side is the slave?

[image]

Comment: doesn't matter. Which is can be pulled LOW there is provision to know from other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter which one the slave or master. It works in two directions.